# Do grouped conditionals work properly in VBScript?

Tags: windows, if-statement, vbscript, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I am writing some rather complex code in VBScript.  I've always known that VBScript only has bitwise, not logical AND and OR operators, so lazy logic doesn't work. [This MS Blog article explains it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/15/184431.aspx).

What I want to know (the article doesn't spell it out) is if you can use grouped conditional statements without having to resort to nested IF statements.

Like so:

```
If A = True OR (B = True AND C = True) Then    '<-- will this statement evaluate correctly?
    ....
End If
```

Instead of having to do this:

```
If A = True Then
    If B = True AND C = True Then
        ...
    End If
End If
```

Will that work?

Will other forms of this statement work as well (i.e. `If A OR B (NOT C)`, etc)?

Comment: What does "work properly" mean in this context? Is your question whether the first example will use lazy logic to only evaluate B and/or C if necessary?

Comment: No. I don't know how to make the question any more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition

```
If A = True Or (B = True And C = True) Then
  ...
End If
```

will work as you'd expect. Same goes for the condition without comparison operations:

```
If A Or (B And C) Then
  ...
End If
```

BTW, note that the above conditions do not have the same meaning as the nested conditional below.

```
If A = True Then
  If B = True And C = True Then
    ...
  End If
End If
```

The statement block in this code snippet would be executed only if *both* conditions are true, not if just one of them is true. A (rather clumsy) equivalent to `A Or (B And C)` could look somewhat like this:

```
If A = True Then
  ...
ElseIf B = True And C = True Then
  ...
End If
```

with both statement blocks containing the same instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The MS Blog entry I linked to specifically warns against using an if condition without an explicit comparison in VBScript because the results may not be what you expect. Also you're right about the nested statement. I just threw the example together and didn't even pick up on that :-)